# Unicode Characters in Command Prompt

Tags: java, unicode, terminal, command-prompt, blackjack

I am making a blackjack game in java and I need to print suits. At first I did that by using `(char)3, (char)4, (char)5, (char)6` and changing the command prompt font to Raster font. That worked for me. However, I could not see the characters on my linux computer. So, I solved that problem by changing my code to use these unicode codes: `"\u2666", "\u2665", "\u2663", "\u2660"` and then that worked. Just to check, I ran my program on windows OS and I realized that I can't see the suits in the command prompt.  I can't find a way to display suits in both OS using one code. Is there a way I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

On Command Prompt to use UTF-8 you can use the command
`chcp 65001`. 
And Lucida Console should be your set font too (right-click on title bar > Properties > Font).